# XAML Force logout (force page navigation)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I have a helper class containing a method LogOut().
This is supposed to be logging of the user and redirect it to the LoginPage.

For some reason, it ignores the page navigation.
It should be able to be called anywhere in the application at any point in code execution.

```
public static class AuthHelper
{
    public static void Logout()
    {
        //cleaning some stored credentials here...

        //force back to app start
        Frame frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
        frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
    }
```

Comment: I would keep all UI navigation logic inside the frame it belongs to, and not do such navigations "outside".  I would limit the role of AuthHelper.LogOut() to save any content / settings before exiting, but it would not be responsible for which page is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user to the login page anywhere in your app you can do it like this:
`Window.Current.Content = new LogInView()`
this will also clear the navigation history of your root frame, making it impossible to go back.

Comment: Exactly what i have been looking for.